# Combining rails search modes 'matches' and 'LIKE'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

The following two methods are useful but incomplete.
1:

```
@individuals = Individual.where("name_last LIKE ?", "%" + params[:q] + "%" ).or(Individual.where("name_first LIKE ?", "%" + params[:q] + "%" )).page params[:page]
```

Finds substrings but in a case sensitive manner

```
params[:q] = 'ari'
```

will return

```
['Marie', 'Maria', 'Marion']
```

but will fail to find `Arianna` as the latter's value in the database starts with an uppercase character.
2.

```
i = Individual.arel_table
@individuals = Individual.where(i[:name_last].matches(params[:q] + "%")).or(Individual.where(i[:name_first].matches(params[:q] + "%"))).page params[:page]
```

will find `Arianna` but not the above array.

How can `matches` and `LIKE` be combined to find all four mentioned cases, in a *single statement*, ideally in a database agnostic way (postgresql is used in this case)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use ILIKE instead of LIKE

ILIKE operator is used in the same way as the LIKE operator. The difference is that ILIKE allows you to perform case-insensitive pattern matching